# How to bring floated window on top above another in dwm window manager?

Tags: xorg, window-manager, dwm

Sometimes when at desktop 1, I switch from float mode to tiled mode, and then back. On desktop 2 for example: shell windows overlaps chrome window, how to send it back...? Also would be nice to switch float/tiled mode only for ***one*** desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the [pertag](http://dwm.suckless.org/patches/pertag) patch for that.